# VBA: turning a 1x1 matrix into an integer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 1x1 array from the following:

```
Dim wbottom As Variant
wbottom = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.transpose(e), wtop)
```

I'm trying to get the number in the array. wbottom(0,0) and wbottom(1,1) give "subscript out of range". ReDim-ming gives nothing when I try to print out the number with MsgBox. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can't you just access the 'first element' of the matrix instead of attempting to carry the 'entire matrix' [I understand this resolves to the same thing]?

Comment: How? Dim x as Integer; x = ???

Comment: Shouldn't it just be x = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.transpose(e), wtop)(0,0)? To denote the element of the array first in the list of both dimensions? I am assuming the matrix function automatically uses a 2-dimensional array starting at 0.

Comment: Same error, subscript out of range.

Comment: what is the value of VarType(wbottom)?

Comment: 8204? I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resulting matrix is 1x1, the resulting array is 1-dimensional, with the only valid subscript being 1. See below, where `A1:E1` and `A3:A7` contain values for a 1x5 and 5x1 matrix respectively (so that the multiplication results in a 1x1 matrix):

```
Sub mmultTest()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = WorksheetFunction.MMult(Range("A1:E1"), Range("A3:A7"))
    Debug.Print LBound(v)
    Debug.Print UBound(v)
    Debug.Print v(1)
End Sub
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
1
55
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
wbottom = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(e, wtop)
```

Transposing a column into a row and then multiplying it by a column to get a 1x1 matrix gives you a 1x1 matrix whose sole element is the dot-product of the two columns. The function `SumProduct` *is* the dot product already, and doesn't require transposing and then unpacking the value.

To test this, I set up a worksheet to look like

```
    A  B
   ------
    1  4
    2  5
    3  6
```

then ran the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, product As Variant

    Set A = Range("A1:A3")
    Set B = Range("B1:B3")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        product = .MMult(.Transpose(A), B) 'what you have
        Debug.Print TypeName(product)
        Debug.Print product(1)

        product = .SumProduct(A, B)
        Debug.Print TypeName(product)
        Debug.Print product
    End With
End Sub
```

with the resulting output:

```
Variant()
 32 
Double
 32
```